# Trouble setting up php Zend include path

Tags: php, zend-framework, include-path

I am trying to set up a PHP path to my Zend Framework. I am very confused on how to do this. My Zend Framework is located at the following location on my server:

amazon/ZendFramework-1.10.3-minimal

I am going to be creating a couple of php files in the amazon/ directory that will require the Zend Framework. My include path is:

```
include("ZendFramework-1.10.3-minimal/library/Zend/Service/Amazon.php");
```

However inside of Amazon.php is the line

```
require_once 'Zend/Rest/Client.php';
```

...and then Client.php has more dependencies set up like that, and so on.

How can I set up my include path so that Amazon.php and Client.php (and so on) can correctly reference the location of the Zend Framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to set your include path using set_include_path() in your **Bootstrap** file if you are using any. (need to check the ZF layout for details if you are using the ZF).

The Loading of the classes will be handled by the Zend Loader when you include the library/Zend/Loader.php file and calling the function that will enable the automatic loading of classes that reside in your library/Zend folder.

When you set the include path to your library, include the library/Zend/Loader.php and call Zend_Loader::registerAutoLoad() I believe will be able to work without problems.

Short example in a file called bootstrap.php

```
set_include_path('ZendFramework-1.10.3-minimal/library/'.get_include_path());
require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```

Comment: The above example did the trick, thank you! Small note: remove the accidental semicolon after library/

Comment: sorry about that...just trying to get it right fast...good to know it helped you.

Comment: The semicolon is actually needed, and you should be appending your include_path to the end, not the start.